# InitializeComponent throws exception .resources not found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-assembly

After a migration from C# 3.5 to 4 we started having an exception of a .resources file not found on InitializeComponent:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MYASSEMBLY.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is a WPF assembly, that is loaded on-demand, and doesn't have localization - the .resources doesn't and shouldn't exist. The issue didn't happen before migration, and happens only when a specific set of actions is performed in the application. In another action, the assembly is loaded correctly, and Fusion Logs show that there were attempts to load the .resources, that failed, but there were no exceptions thrown.

Also, an old blog post about debugging assembly load specifically puts it:

> Note: Unless you are explicitly debugging the failure of a resource to load, you will likely want to ignore failures to find assemblies with the “.resources” extension with the culture set to something other than “neutral”. Those are expected failures when the ResourceManager is probing for satellite assemblies.
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/debugging-assembly-loading-failures/

I have tried applying the NeutralResourcesLanguage attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs, but that only made the exception reference another, 3rd party, assembly.

What might be the cause for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by a badly written AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event handler in another assembly that is dynamically loaded, combined with a change in .Net behavior. The dynamic load nature of those assemblies explaining the reason for sometimes not seeing the error.

Adding a try-catch on InitializeComponent and inspecting the exception showed that the Inner Exception had in the stack trace the call that attempted to load the .resources dll - the badly written event handler.

That already existed before, in .Net 3.5, but in .Net 4 there was a change:

> Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the ResolveEventHandler event is raised for all assemblies, including resource assemblies. In earlier versions, the event was not raised for resource assemblies. If the operating system is localized, the handler might be called multiple times: once for each culture in the fallback chain.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1